# Unable to enable group access tokens in public GitLab group (Owner role)

Tags: gitlab, access-token

I created a public group with multiple subgroups on https://gitlab.com. Since I would like various repos within the groups to interact with each other (e.g. access container and/or package registries), I wanted to add some access tokens. In all repos, subgroups and even group I get this:

[image]

I checked all subroupgs and groups settings and couldn't find anything mentioning access tokens. So I followed the [link to the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/settings/group_access_tokens.html#enable-or-disable-group-access-token-creation) but the information that is there appears to be incorrect since there is no mention of

> Users can create project access tokens and group access tokens in this group

anywhere in the (sub)group's permissions settings. Am I missing something? This feature should be available for all tiers and setups according to the documentation (see top of the linked page).

---

In regards to the Group Access Tokens option the document actually does state:

> Offering: SaaS, self-managed

So even though all tiers are covered, it's the type of hosting that is the deal breaker here if you are using https://gitlab.com as I do.

In addition it appears that all chances of creating project (not group!) access tokens (except `CI_JOB_TOKEN` of course) is disabled too. I though of using a combo between access tokens and variables to connect my repos but that appears to not be an option at all!

Comment: Is this a comment or a question? Today I came also across a similar problem. It seems that on gitlab.com it is part of the paid tier, but it is still available on the free SaaS tier.

Comment: I am looking  for alternatives. So it is a question. I will try to improve it.

Comment: @maro12 or perhaps  you can give a suggestion?

Comment: My current workflow only involves self-hosted solutions, which can create group and project tokens (free tier). As said before, you can not create group or project tokens on the free tier on gitlab.com. One alternative maybe is using GitHub's OAuth, see https://docs.github.com/en/apps/oauth-apps/building-oauth-apps/creating-an-oauth-app. But I have not tried it.